# Where does entery saved for View and Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am not able to find the file where the entry get saved that which controller is for which view.

i am facing a issue that i have created a controller and then right clicked on it and generated a .ascx  user control. but it generates it in HOME directory but when i move that .ascx to shared folder its not link with controller.

plez tell me how to create a user control in shared folder and set its controller.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't set a controller to a view. It works by convention. The controller action will first look at the `~/Views/ControllerName` folder for the view and then in `~/Views/Shared`. If the view is in some non-standard location you could specify its location when returning it:

```
return PartialView("~/Views/SomeLocation/SomeView.ascx");
```